# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'. online jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

Can anyone help me  with this issue. I'm tying to do an algorithm in online Jupyterlite. But it's giving the above error.

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

ModuleNotFoundError means that you are missing the right package.
If you use Jupyterlite you can add the following at the top of your notebook:

```
import piplite
await piplite.install('seaborn')
```

Comment: To add more background in this rapidly developing ecosystem, elsewhere you may see `micropip` used to install in JupyterLite. As stated [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/using.html),`piplite` is a wrapper around [micropip](https://test-pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pypi.html).

Answer (score 0):

Import following Line, then run

**import piplite
await piplite.install('seaborn')**

[image]